# Wordpress multisite patch

Tags: wordpress

Hello i have wp multisite

```
new.barmaraia.com
```

This multisite have 3 blogs

`new.barmaraia.com` -first
`new.barmaraia.com/beach/` -second
`new.barmaraia.com/fussion/` - third

I need first blog open on this adress
`new.barmaraia.com/classic` , i use new.barmaraia.com for other needs(entry page with banner links to all 3 blogs). How make

first blog lands on

```
new.barmaraia.com/classic/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the following links :

http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL